# What's the difference between "children" and "element" props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm upgrading to React Router 6. The [migration guide](https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/upgrading/v5#replace-useroutematch-with-usematch) suggests using the following syntax when declaring routes:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/">
    <Home />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/users">
    <Users />
  </Route>
</Switch>
```

`Switch` is now renamed to `Routes`, but that's beside the point. When trying this syntax I get an error:

> `<MyComponent>` is not a `<Route>` component. All component children of `<Routes>` must be a `<Route>` or `<React.Fragment>`

Using `element` instead of component children works, but I can't find in the [docs](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route) what's the difference between the `element` prop and component children, nor the motivation for this requirement.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Why does `<Route>` have an `element` prop instead of `render` or `component`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/faq#why-does-route-have-an-element-prop-instead-of-render-or-component) of the official FAQ likely covers/explains/answers your question why the `element` prop exists.

The `element` prop is for rendering routed content, the `children` prop (*not used directly*) is only used to nest `Route` components, i.e. the `Route` component can only be rendered by the `Routes` component or other `Route` components.

[`element` prop](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#element)

> The element to render when the route matches the URL.
>
> ```
> <Route path="/for-sale" element={<Properties />} />
> ```

["children" prop](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#children)

> (TODO: need to talk about nesting, maybe even a separate doc)

example:

```
<Route path="/foo" element={<Foo />}>      // <-- "/foo"
  <Route path="bar element={<FooBar />} /> // <-- "/foo/bar"
</Route>
```

An easier way to see this might be to see the routes configuration "view" which uses the [`useRoutes` hook](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-routes) (*used by the `Routes` component as an [implementation detail](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router/lib/components.tsx#L383)*).

Example:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/foo",
    element: <Foo />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "bar",
        element: <FooBar />,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Here's it is fairly obvious the `children` are the nested routes while the `element`s are the content to render.

Comment: Does this mean the [migration guide](https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/upgrading/v5#replace-useroutematch-with-usematch) is outdated?

Comment: @Septagram No? It seems the migration guide perfectly covers the switch from `Switch` to `Routes` and all the route conversion in [Upgrade all `<Switch>` elements to `<Routes>`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5#upgrade-all-switch-elements-to-routes). You might need to read past the first code example which only shows the RRDv5 syntax/API to see the rest of the conversion to RRDv6.